# Docker build does not create an image but the application starts anyway

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile

Currently I am running windows with docker for windows installed.
I have made a java application in Spring Boot that I want to build an image of and run in a docker container.

What am I doing wrong?
When I run the bellow and can see in my cmd prompt that the application starts and run. But there is no image in in docker and nothing running there.

```
#
# Build stage
#
FROM maven:3.8.4-openjdk-17 AS build
COPY src /test/src
COPY pom.xml /test
#RUN mvn -f /test/pom.xml clean package
RUN mvn -f /test/pom.xml clean package

#
# Package stage
#
FROM openjdk:17-alpine
COPY --from=build /test/target/test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /usr/local/lib/test.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/usr/local/lib/test.jar"]
```

What am I missing?

I have the application in a folder /test and the Dockerfile is also under /test. I go to this location in the cmd prompt and enter:

docker build -t testapp .

Comment: What do you mean by `But there is no image in docker and nothing running there.`? Did you check the image using the command `docker images -a` and the container using `docker ps -a`?

Comment: please paste the command to run docker build as well as the full output.

Comment: `docker build` only creates an image, it doesn't run your app. What makes you think your app started?

Comment: @metadata yes I have run does commands and nothing except for the headers in the result

Comment: How you started your app? If image is not ready? you must have ran docker run <image>. What is the value of image you used? Please share commands and logs

Comment: @LeiYang I think the command is in my question already.    docker build -t testapp .

Comment: we need the full output.

Comment: I found out that test was starting so by setting <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip> the build was finished and I got the image which I now can start. So basically I was doing the right thing but the build was not finally built due to test started and no image was created.

Comment: so your question isn't a question at all. you thought docker wasn't build, but it is in build process(running tests). you thought the container was running, but it is the tests running, before docker build completed.

Answer (score 2):

The command you are running, `docker build -t testapp .`, only creates the docker image that you can check with the command someone stated in the comments : `docker images -a`.

To run the image in a docker container you must use the run command : `docker run testapp`. Then you will see the container in the Docker app.

Comment: As I wrote. I stand in the folder /test where I have the Dockerfile. I write in the command prompt  "docker build -t testapp ." and then I can see load build definition from Dockerfile and it starts to do the things in the dockerfile stated in the question. After finish it starts the application as it is stated in the entrypoint and i can see in the cmd prompt that things is starting to happened. In this case to testit I have made a for loop that write out a increasing number every 10 seconds. When I write docker images -a there is nothing.

Comment: I found out that test was starting so by setting <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip> the build was finished and I got the image which I now can start. So basically I was doing the right thing but the build was not finally built due to test started.

Comment: Makes sense. If you don't want to run the tests, you can avoid copying them in first place and update the COPY command in the Dockerfile like this: COPY src /test/src/main

Answer (score 0):

docker build will only build docker image
if you want to run the image in your docker try running the command

```
docker run  testapp
```

docker build [builds a new image from the source code](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/).

docker [create creates a writeable container from the image and prepares it for running.](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/create/)

docker run [creates the container (same as docker create) and runs it.](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/)

Comment: I found out that test was starting so by setting <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip> the build was finished and I got the image which I now can start. So basically I was doing the right thing but the build was not finally built due to test started.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing everything correct except for that when I thought the image was ready/built I run test of my java application that looked as the application had started.

By setting <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip> I skipped the test and the build was finished. I got the image which I now can start. Thank you all for your question and assistance.